# Possible to login without the digits in the password

Tags: php, crypt

I just discovered that my password-protected area is not that protected. Passwords are required to use digits. Now, if the password has the digits at the end, somehow the login is accepted as long as the a-z part of the password is correct. Why is that and how can I correct that?  (PHP 5.4.28)

```
function generate_hash($password)
{
    $salt = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(22);
    $salt = '$2a$%13$' . strtr($salt, array('_' => '.', '~' => '/'));
    return crypt($password, $salt);

}

$bind = array(":email" => $email, ":password" => crypt($password, generate_hash($password) ) );
            $results = $db->select("users", 'email=:email AND password=:password', $bind);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know about the specifics of your problem, but you're using the hash completely wrong. To use `crypt`, you do the following:

On registration:

- create a random salt
- create the `$salt` argument in a proper format: `$2a$xx$...` (note: no `%`, that may contribute to the problem)
- hash the password with `crypt($password, $salt)`
- store the hash in the database

On login:

- retrieve the password hash from the database based on the entered email
- generate a hash using `crypt($enteredPassword, $databaseHash)`
- compare the two hashes

You're not doing that at all. You should probably also use [`password_hash`](http://php.net/password_hash) instead, which takes care of a lot of pitfalls in the usage of the raw `crypt` API.

Comment: `password_hash` isn't available in PHP 5.4.*

Comment: @DenisV https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat, even linked from the manual

Comment: Thank you that seems to be it!